# How to specify external location for image store in Spring Boot 2.0 web app?

Tags: spring, image, spring-boot

Currently I have images stored in /src/main/resources/static/myimages in the project directory. Now I want to move these outside of project directory like in /Users/tom/myimages  so that in img tag src="/myimages/subdir/first.jpg" in the HTML markup will be loaded from /Users/tom/myimages/subdir/first.jpg.  How can I achieve this in spring boot 2.0 project?

This will allow me to add new images without having to recompile the project in production environment.

Comment: Maybe you could create a symbolic link from "/Users/tom/myimages" to "/src/main/resources/static/myimages"? The images are outside your project, but you can still reference to them in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve this, by `PathResourceResolver` which is the simplest resolver and its purpose is to find a resource given a public URL pattern. In fact, this is the default resolve.

### Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry
               .addResourceHandler("/myimages/**")
               .addResourceLocations("/Users/tom/myimages")
               .setCachePeriod(3600)
               .resourceChain(true)
               .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

### Description:

- We are registering the `PathResourceResolver` in the resource chain as the sole `ResourceResolver` in it.
- the html code that, in conjunction with the `PathResourceResolver`, locates the `/first.jpg` file in the `/Users/tom/myimages` folder

Comment: Only thing is if we need to serve Images from external location we will need to add "file:/"  like .addResourceLocations("file:/Users/tom/myimages") same as in answer by @Sh Pavel

Comment: If you need to define a dir like `/home/.../images/profileImages/user.png` then you need to define it like `addResourceHandler("/images/**")` and `addResourceLocations("file:/home/.../images")` and get it like this `/images/profileImages/user.png` ?

Answer (score 5):

May be you should try to define your own static resource handler ?

It will override the default one.

Something like this:

```js
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:/path/to/my/folder/");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
That one is something seems to be work on some of my old projects:

```js
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class CustomWebMvcAutoConfig extends
                    WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    String myExternalFilePath = "file:///C:/Users/tom/imgs/";

    registry.addResourceHandler("/imgs/**").addResourceLocations(myExternalFilePath);

    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can u explain your answer? Does it mean if any path having 'imgs' in it will now be loaded from C:/Users/tom/imgs/ ?

Comment: @ace yes, it is

Answer (score 2):

[Spring 5 - Static Resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

From the documentation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").
                      addResourceLocations("classpath:/my-custom-location/","C:/spark/Hadoop/my-custom-location/");


        }
}
```

or You can store Image path in Database. Load it in dynamically when ever required also you can change that path on fly.

HTML Code Will be like this :-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">


<link href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>' rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/app.js"/>'></script>

</head>
<body>
   <h1 id="title" class="color1">Spring MVC- Static Resource Mapping Example</h1>

   <button onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
   <hr />

   <img alt="http://mytechnologythought.blogspot.com" src="<spring:url value="/pages/img01.png"/>" width="200">
</body>
</html>
```

[Here Full Example Reference Blog link](https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-5-static-resources-handling-example)
Note :-  The type WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Comment: it is not clear from your answer. Can u make it specific to my question. My question gives different paths. Does your answer means if any path that has 'pages' in it will now be loaded from C:/spark/Hadoop/my-custom-location/ ? and what is the meaning of classpath:/my-custom-location? Can u elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are very good .but the correct way to do this would according to spring boot docs .you need to add the following property to the application.properties file

spring.resources.static-locations=file:/home/username/images/

The mvc static path pattern is not necessary
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**

http://localhost:8080/resources/exampleimage.png

The resource path we mentioned would be added to the list of the default resources locations

please read the docs for more info
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content