# How to specify external location for image store

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I am using spring boot auto configuration
I uploaded my images to a folder outside static folder named 'images'
How can I access them and then show them in my jsp page without restarting whole project

my failed attempts ->

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/abc.jpg">
<img src="/images/abc.jpg">
```

but it accesses the static folder
How can I get out of this folder and show these uploaded images in jsp page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883955/how-to-specify-external-location-for-image-store-in-spring-boot-2-0-web-app

Comment: you can use `setStaticLocations` from [ResourceProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ResourceProperties.html#setStaticLocations-java.lang.String:A-) to define static locations for your resources.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu do i have to create new configuration class as i am using spring boot

Comment: Yes that new class need to implement `WebMvcConfigurer` interface

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu as i implement this method it is replacing default static folder. So i get this error  "javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'"